How can I install biomaRt without getting an error?
I have problems installing the biomaRt library (Error in library(biomaRt) : there is no package called 'biomaRt')
I have reinstalled rtools, run as administrator Rstudio, used the functions:
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("ropensci/biomaRt")

But I get the following error:
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
 HTTP Error 404.
 Not found

I have also tried to download the biomartr_1.0.7.tar.gz file and install it and it gives me also error (I have tried different installation paths):
> install.packages("C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/biomartr_1.0.7.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before continuing:

I am running out of options, can someone help me. I greatly appreciate it
I have tried all of the above options and none of them worked.

There are two related packages with very similar names ({biomaRt} and {biomartr}) and I think you're mixing the installation instructions for the two, which is why this isn't working.
If you want {biomaRt} hosted by Bioconductor you can install with:
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("biomaRt")

If you're trying to use {biomartr}, which is provided by ropensci you can use:
install.packages("biomartr", dependencies = TRUE)


